# Using scala's filter on a list of pairs

Tags: list, scala, filter

I am trying to filter a list that contains pairs.

For example my list is

List((1,2),(3,4),(5,2))

I want to use filter to filter the list to only contain answers where the first number in the pair is greater than the second. How can I do this?

So, The resulting list would be

List((5,2))

Comment: you should at least try something. you can read about List.filter and about pair (tuples) everywhere. Tuples: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_tuples.htm

List api: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/#scala.collection.immutable.List

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter for first number in pair is greater than second:

```
val ls = List((1,2),(3,4),(4,5),(6,2)) 
ls.filter(pair => pair._1 > pair._2) // List((6, 2))
```

Comment: thank you! So, how does scala know what "pair" is when you write pair in the code?
Oh I see. You can call that whatever you want. If I understand correctly, are you simply telling it, for each pair in the list, look at the first element (_1) and compare it to the second element (_2)?

Comment: You can call it whatever you want. Pair is a type of Tuple (Tuple2 to be precise). You can reference the elements of Tuples like tuple_1, tuple_2, tuple_3 etc. For ex: `val tuple = (10,11,12,13)  // tuple._4 == 13`

Answer (score 4):

Your example doesn't make sense, but I guess you still want to filter your list on some predicate.

The easier is to deconstruct the pair:

```
scala> val l = List((1,2), (3,4), (4,5))
l: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (3,4), (4,5))
scala> l.filter { case (a, b) => a > b }
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List()
```

Comment: Sorry, I had swapped the condition. Samar helped me edit it and it is updated now.

Comment: I generally prefer the destructuring approach here, and almost never use the `_1` accessors, as a matter of style. But to each their own!